# Is it possible to re-use branch GitLab pipeline for merge request?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I push to GitLab, a pipeline is triggered. When I create a merge request, a new pipeline is created even though there were no actual changes since both pipelines run on exact same commit. Is it possible to re-use the branch pipeline in the MR somehow without creating a new one if it's on the same commit?

Comment: If you don't need the push pipeline, you can disable it and only run pipeline on MR. Otherwise, I don't think you can "reuse" a pipeline as they could have very different jobs (job can be enabled to run only on push or MR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MR pipelines are enabled, merge requests will always use the MR pipeline. You can't "reuse" the branch pipeline for an MR pipeline, but you have a few options here that are close:

1. Use MR pipelines while an MR is open, but otherwise create a branch pipeline.
2. Disable MR pipelines -- use branch pipelines exclusively

From the documentation, [Switch between branch pipelines and merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines):

> The following example is for a project that runs branch and merge request pipelines only, but does not run pipelines for any other case. It runs:
>
> - Branch pipelines when a merge request is not open for the branch.
> - Merge request pipelines when a merge request is open for the branch.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

To break this down: the first rule allows merge request pipelines. The second rule *prevents* branch pipelines from being created when an MR is already open. The third rule allows branch pipelines when an MR is *not* open.

Otherwise, you can disable MR pipelines entirely, in which case your MRs will use the branch pipeline for its status checks:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: never
    - when: always
```